Use managed identity with azure service bus messaging
I have been trying to Spring Messaging Azure Service Bus (as described here) with a managed identity. However, I get a bunch of error messages from ChainedTokenCredential, including "Azure Identity => Attempted credential ManagedIdentityCredential is unavailable". I tried setting managed-identity-enabled: true and client-id in spring. cloud.azure.servicebus.credential..., or cloud.azure.servicebus.producer.credential...
With the Spring Cloud Azure Service Bus Starter it worked fine, but I would prefer to use the messaging features to be able to interact with multiple queues.

Can tell it only from the .NET side - there we normally use DefaultAzureCredentials. Maybe it is worth a shot to use them?

But are you able to insert the DefaultAzureCredentials object into the azure service bus autoconfig? or are you doing all the configuration programatically?

services.AddAzureClients(clientBuilder =>
{
clientBuilder.AddServiceBusClientWithNamespace(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ServiceBus:Connection__fullyQualifiedNamespace"));
clientBuilder.UseCredential(new DefaultAzureCredential());
});
this is what I use in C# in the DI setup

In case anyone else faces the same issue: when using the spring-messaging-azure-servicebus library, even though properties like spring.cloud.azure.servicebus.credential.client-id are valid (since they are part of the generic azure autoconfigure package), aren't actually used. It does work however if you set AZURE_CLIENT_ID as an env variable.
